# Acces class variable in dictionary initializer syntax C#

Tags: c#

```
   public class MenuBar
    {
        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//i[@class='r-icon icon-meter']")]
        private IWebElement mnuItemDashboard;

        [FindsBy(How = How.XPath, Using = "//i[@class='r-icon icon-office']")]
        private IWebElement mnuItemData;

        public static enum MenuItem
        {
            Dashboard,
            Data
        }

        private Dictionary<MenuItem, IWebElement> menuItemdict =
        {
            {MenuItem.Dashboard, mnuItemDashboard}, //mnuItemDashboard is not visible/accessible here.
            {MenuItem.Data, mnuItemData} //mnuItemData is not visible/accessible here.
        }
}
```

I'm using dictionary initializer syntax to intialize `menuItemdict`. But while doing it doesn't see the class variables `mnuItemDashboard` and `mnuItemData` how can I make them available in the dictionary initializer syntax?

Comment: This is not an array initializer, this is a dictionary initializer. You cannot do what you want in a field initializer. Move your `menuItemdict` initialization code to constructor.

Comment: @dymanoid doing it in the constructor would I be `menuItemdict.Add()` them all one by one?

Comment: No, you can use the same initializer syntax, but prepend it with `new Dictionary<MenuItem, IWebElement>`.

Comment: Thanks got it! Didn't know I could use the initializer syntax inside the constructor.